# Spring Data MongoDB Core 1.9.1.RELEASE gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/geo/GeoResults

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using XML configuration to create `MongoTemplate` bean and the XML looks like:

```
<bean id="user" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="${mongodb.username}" />
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="${mongodb.password}" />
</bean>

<mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="${mongodb.replica.set}">
        <mongo:options connections-per-host="${mongodb.connections.per.host}"
            threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="${mongodb.connections.block.thread}"
            slave-ok="true" write-number="1" write-timeout="0" write-fsync="true" />
</mongo:mongo>

<bean id="readPreferenceSecondary" class="com.mongodb.TaggableReadPreference.SecondaryReadPreference">
</bean>
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" autowire="byType">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongodb.name}" />
        <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="user" />
        <property name="readPreference" ref="readPreferenceSecondary" />
</bean>
```

My pom dependencies are:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This gives me the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scenarioRepository': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate
>   com.airtel.agile.decision.tree.repositories.impl.ScenarioRepositoryImpl.mongoTemplate;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/data/geo/GeoResults

How to get this thing working?

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Added the following dependency and the code worked fine. It was picking up an older version otherwise.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```